# Is it possible to call a UIEvent between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, uievent

Is it possible to handle UIEvents between viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear?
For example:

Let's say I have a view controller with a UITableView.
When pressing a cell I push a another view controller to the navigation controller (And display it of course).
Is it possible that after the viewWillAppear event of the pushed view (And before the viewDidAppear) I can still press one of the cells in the UITableView?

I am asking this because I am seeing this in the logs of my application and I Never thought that such a thing could be possible..

What do you guys(Or girls) think?
Thanks!

Comment: well, as far as i know, you can't unless you use multithreading, because while the view is generated on viewWillAppear, all userInteraction and process are halt until all the line in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are compiled

Comment: How is it possible to use multithreading and bypass this? When the viewWillAppear finishes I don't have any chance to do any other activity.. I can't prevent the viewDidAppear from occuring (Unless I pop the view in viewWillAppear). Still, It's very strange that I came across this. I think that the logs are accurate..

Comment: im not very good at multithreading so u might want to find another source. but i think you can do it with dispatch_queue, try googling for GCD (grand central dispatch)

Comment: Anyway, that is not the case with my code but thanks anyway :) Anyone else thinks diffrently?

Answer (score 1):

I have one idea may this work,
you use performSelector in viewWillAppear with 0.01 or another time with Delay Parameter and call your method here,

hope,this help you.
:)

Comment: This might work, But I don't have such a code in my program. I am not trying to use some artificial delays and such. All I am asking is, is it possible to have some UI interaction between viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad - see the scenario I described above.